# Python list of lists with strings with regex

Tags: python, regex, list

`segmented` is a list of lists. Each element could be list of one or more string elements. And each string element is of the form:

`Block1: some strings`
`Block2: some strings`

Now not all string elements need to have `Block2`.
I want to run a loop where each element in 'segmented' is selected and then further loops with the secondary elements and tests for `Block2`. If present the string after `Block2` is selected. IF there are more than 1 secondary elements then all the string is joined to a single string. The code I tried is as below

```
blk2 = re.compile(r'Block2:(.*)', re.DOTALL)
list1 = []
for i in segmented:
    secondlist = []
    for j in i:
      if re.search(blk2, j).group(1) is not None: # testing if Block2 exists
         txt = re.search(blk2, j).group(1) # picking up strings after Block2.
         secondlist.append(txt) #appending the string to an intermediate list
         '\n'.join(secondlist) #if there are more than 1 element in secondlist joining them to one element
         list1.append(secondlist[0]) # appending the joined element to  list1
```

I keep getting `NoneType` errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `secondlist.append(txt)`: but `txt` can be `None` if regex doesn't match

Comment: if there is block2 in an element there is always some text after it. So the regex can't return None. But some of the elements may not have Block2 at all which I hoped would be eliminated by if re.search(blk2, j).group(1) is not None:

Comment: don't perform the search twice. Store the search in a variable... and provide traceback of the error, don't just describe it

Comment: BTW `'\n'.join(secondlist)` does nothing useful since you don't store the result...

Comment: so '\n'.join(secondlist) should be stored as another variable?

Comment: I couldn't traceback the error as I deleted the code and was trying something else. But this problem came back to me so have provided the general nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is row:

```
if re.search(blk2, j).group(1) is not None:
```

This code fails when `j` contains only `Block1` (no `Block2`).
In such case `search` does not match anything, so the result of `search`
is `None`.

Then, on `None` object (of type `NoneType`), you attempt to call `group(1)`
which raises exception `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Another remark: There is no need to call `search` twice, as you did.

So change this fragment to:

```
m = re.search(blk2, j)
if m:
    txt = m.group(1)
```

Additional hints:

1. Change the regex to `r'Block2:\s*(.*)'` (I added `\s*`).
   This way you avoid keeping initial space(s) from each `Block2`, if any.
2. It is not clear, why you use `secondlist`.
   Maybe you should add the strings matched directly to `list1`.

Comment: thanks Valdi_Bo. I though that re.search().group() would be evaluated to None if Block2 is not present. Your explanation has made it clear where I went wrong and thanks to you I have rectified my code.